# converting SSRS report to Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have this code to convert over to CR. I am having the most issue with converting @ReportType over to a formula and parameter to CR. Any suggestions of what to do? I am stumped and no support at work.

```
    select i.IncidentTypeDescription, 
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.IncidentStartedDateTime, i.IncidentDate)), 0) as avgrectoinit, 
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.IncidentDate, i.FirstUnitDispatchedTime)), 0) as avginittodisp, 
    isnull(abs(sum(datediff(second, i.FirstUnitDispatchedTime, i.FirstUnitArrivedTime))), 0) as avgdisptoarrive, 
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.FirstUnitArrivedTime, i.RouteClosedTime)), 0) as avgarrivetoclose, 
    count(*) as reccount
FROM MV_Incident i
WHERE i.IncidentNumber LIKE N'bvpd%'
    AND i.ReportNumber LIKE N'bvpd%'
    and i.IncidentStartedDateTime >= @StartDate
    and i.IncidentStartedDateTime <  dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
    and (
        (@ReportType = 'All') and (i.CallSource = i.CallSource or i.CallSource is null) or
        (@ReportType = 'Officer' and (i.CallSource in ('Officer', 'Mobile', 'Field Initiated', 'Mobile Initiated'))) or
        (@ReportType = 'NonOfficer' and (i.CallSource not in ('Officer', 'Mobile', 'Field Initiated', 'Mobile Initiated') or i.CallSource is NULL))
        )
group by i.IncidentTypeDescription
order by i.IncidentTypeDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query as it is in crystal reports using the command option while creating a database connection.

Second option would be, USe the below query and create parameters and write your conditions in record selection formula which will add where clause to crystal reports.

```
select i.IncidentTypeDescription, i.IncidentNumber ,i.ReportNumber ,i.CallSource ,
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.IncidentStartedDateTime, i.IncidentDate)), 0) as avgrectoinit, 
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.IncidentDate, i.FirstUnitDispatchedTime)), 0) as avginittodisp, 
    isnull(abs(sum(datediff(second, i.FirstUnitDispatchedTime, i.FirstUnitArrivedTime))), 0) as avgdisptoarrive, 
    isnull(sum(datediff(second, i.FirstUnitArrivedTime, i.RouteClosedTime)), 0) as avgarrivetoclose, 
    count(*) as reccount
FROM MV_Incident i
group by i.IncidentTypeDescription,i.IncidentNumber ,i.ReportNumber ,i.CallSource 
order by i.IncidentTypeDescription,i.IncidentNumber ,i.ReportNumber ,i.CallSource
```

Now to crystal report design and create two parameters `Start date` and `End Date` and write your where condition as it is in record selection formula as:

```
i.IncidentNumber LIKE N'bvpd%'
    AND i.ReportNumber LIKE N'bvpd%'
    and i.IncidentStartedDateTime >= @StartDate
    and i.IncidentStartedDateTime <  dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
    and (
        (@ReportType = 'All') and (i.CallSource = i.CallSource or i.CallSource is null) or
        (@ReportType = 'Officer' and (i.CallSource in ('Officer', 'Mobile', 'Field Initiated', 'Mobile Initiated'))) or
        (@ReportType = 'NonOfficer' and (i.CallSource not in ('Officer', 'Mobile', 'Field Initiated', 'Mobile Initiated') or i.CallSource is NULL))
        )
```

Don't forget to create reporttype formula.

Let me know incase any issue